# webex interferes with web application

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, webex

I received a complaint about buttons disappearing and odd formatting of a web application that I support.  Upon troubleshooting, it seemed that the only thing new about the environment (which was previously working fine) was the installation of webex on the client machine.

Uninstalling webex resolved the issue.  Please mind that **webex was not being used during the issue**, but it was still causing odd displays and formatting of Internet Explorer pages.

I've always disliked webex because it required reboot to use and the client felt very invasive (gotomeeting can accomplish the same if not better features without being nearly as invasive).

OK, I guess the first few sentences were a frustrated rant.  The question is, what does webex do to mangle Internet Explorer pages (even when webex is not actively being used).

Examples of the mangling are: non appearing buttons; completely overridden css; and javascript errors (when the app has no javascript errors).

Comment: There is a number of products named "Webex". Which one are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check Internet Explorer "add-ons"? I'll bet they've installed an add-on during the installation of their client, which is possibly embedding its own HTML into every page.